# Union of two querysets results in Programming error if one of them is empty

Tags: python, django, orm, django-queryset

To save some db hits I'm trying to use django union to merge two querysets into one, like this:

```py
qs1 = Model1.objects.filter(...) # complicated stuff going on here
qs2 = Model2.objects.filter(...) # complicated stuff going on here

qs1.union(qs2)
```

Of course I'm making sure the fields in both querysets are the same. When querysets are not empty, my code works properly - I'm receiving a single, merged queryset with all the fields I need.

The problem only appears when either of the querysets happens to be empty. When that happens I receive:

```
    def _execute(self, sql, params, *ignored_wrapper_args):
        self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
        with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
            if params is None:
                return self.cursor.execute(sql)
            else:
>               return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
E               django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: each UNION query must have the same number of columns
E               LINE 1: ...app_model1"."id" IS NULL)) UNION (SELECT "app_model1...
E                                                                            ^

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:84: ProgrammingError
```

I feel like the columns should stay in the queryset even if there are no records. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the pipe operator ?

```
qs3 = qs1 | qs2
```

This does not use SQL to perform a UNION, but joins the querysets in after they have been returned

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, but what I'm trying to achieve is to limit database hits to one here, so it has to happen on the database side :(

Comment: I am only guessing, but would you not have 3 queries with the union method?

Comment: No, querysets are lazy, so they won't be evaluated until they have to. Django will build SQL of queryset1, build SQL of queryset2, then modify them with the UNION clause. DB hit with this prepared SQL will happen only in the last line, when I actually ask for the data.